# how to optimize a 'for loop' for 3d complex<double> arrays to improve speed in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab

all the arrays in this code are complex type in this code and the running time for this for loop is about 1 min. Ktemp is an array with size 141*1202*141. could anyone help me to optimize this code and save the running time?

```
 complex<double> ***P1;
        P1 = new complex<double>**[141];
        for (i = 0; i < num_y; i++)
        {
            P1[i] = new complex<double> *[1202];
            for (j = 0; j < tsize; j++)
            {
                P1[i][j] = new complex<double>[141];
            }
        }

        for (int zz = 1; zz < 20; zz++)//in z direction
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 141; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 1202; j++) 
                {
                    for (k = 0; k < 141; k++)
                    {   
                        if (Ktemp[i][j][k].real() <= 0)
                        {
                            P1[i][j][k] = 0;  
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            P1[i][j][k] = excit_pfft[i][j][k] * expn[i][j][k];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            excit_pfft = P1;    
        }
```

my second question is about rewriting matlab function 'fftshift' with C++. I have finished the code, but it seems not that efficient. could anyone help me rewrite this code? my code is attached below:

```
complex<double> ***fftw_shift(complex<double> ***te, int a, int b, int c)
{
    complex<double> ***tempa;
    tempa = new complex<double> **[a];
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        tempa[i] = new complex<double> *[b];
        for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            tempa[i][j] = new complex<double>[c];
        }
    }
    /*for the row*/
    if (c % 2 == 1)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < c / 2; k++)
                {
                    tempa[i][j][k] = te[i][j][k + c / 2 + 1];
                    tempa[i][j][k + c / 2] = te[i][j][k];
                    tempa[i][j][c - 1] = te[i][j][c / 2];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < c / 2; k++)
                {
                    tempa[i][j][k] = te[i][j][k + c / 2];
                    tempa[i][j][k + c / 2] = te[i][j][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }


    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < c; k++)
            {
                te[i][j][k] = tempa[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }


    /*for the column*/
    if (b % 2 == 1)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < b / 2; j++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < c; k++)
                {
                    tempa[i][j][k] = te[i][j + b / 2 + 1][k];
                    tempa[i][j + b / 2][k] = te[i][j][k];
                    tempa[i][b - 1][k] = te[i][b / 2][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < b / 2; j++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < c; k++)
                {
                    tempa[i][j][k] = te[i][j + b / 2][k];
                    tempa[i][j + b / 2][k] = te[i][j][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < c; k++)
            {
                te[i][j][k] = tempa[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }

    /*for the third dimension*/
    if (a % 2 == 1)
    {

        for (i = 0; i < a / 2; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < c; k++)
                {
                    tempa[i][j][k] = te[i + a / 2 + 1][j][k];
                    tempa[i + a / 2][j][k] = te[i][j][k];
                    tempa[a - 1][j][k] = te[a / 2][j][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < a / 2; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < c; k++)
                {
                    tempa[i][j][k] = te[i + a / 2][j][k];
                    tempa[i + a / 2][j][k] = te[i][j][k];

                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < c; k++)
            {
                te[i][j][k] = tempa[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }

    return (te);
}
```

Comment: For starters you should probably try using a single `std::vector` to hold all of the `complex`es, right now you have **170,000** allocations and you're probably suffering from a lot of cache misses.

Comment: In your first code block what is the `zz` loop for?  It seams to be doing nothing but making you iterate through everything 20 times.

Comment: for zz loop: excit_pfft = P1

Comment: @user657267 vector can contain element which is complex number? also,i think vector is less efficient than  array. anyway, I am going to have a try now

Comment: @gugabrielle That still doesn't make ant sense.  you are doing the same thing 20 times.  you don't use `zz` at all and that assignment will be the same from the first time to the last.

Comment: Are you computing a complex exponent by repeated multiplication? Why not just use the pow function in the complex class?

Comment: @samgak but  I have to filter the element that is less than 0 for each loop

Comment: @gugabrielle There's zero cost to using a `vector` vs a heap array if you use `reserve`, leave manual allocations to the c++ history books. Even if you do want to use an array for some reason, make a single allocation instead of thousands and your processor cache will thank you.

Comment: @NathanOliver actually, excit_pfft will be updated in each loop

Comment: @gugabrielle where does KTemp get updated in the loop? If it doesn't then why do you need to recheck it after each multiplication?

Comment: @samgak right. I didn't realize that once the element was set to 0, then it wouldn't change anymore

Comment: @user657267 I tried vector just now. each time i used reserve, I didn't know how to use push_back function, it would show the error: subscript out of range

Comment: @gugabrielle `P1 = new complex<double>**[141];  for (i = 0; i < num_y; i++)`  You hard code `141`, then you use `num_y` to access the array.  So how many entries are there, 141 or `num_y`?

Comment: @gugabrielle `I tried vector just now.`  You should be relieved you got the error.  That means that your program was more than likely incorrect all along, and you never would have known it if you stuck with arrays.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie in this problem: num_y=141=num_x and tszie=1202, but they are not the const value which defined at the beginning. so I can not define an array which is P1[141][1202][141].

Comment: @gugabrielle did you get the out of range error because you used `at`? Because if you didn't it sounds like you are compiling without optimisations  or with debugging, which might slow your code down to a crawl.

Comment: @gugabrielle I forgot to ask you -- are you running a **release**, **optimized** version of your code?  If you're running a debug, unoptimized version, your timings are meaningless.  What you *should* do is fix your out-of-bounds error in debug mode, and once that's fixed, build a release version and time it.

Comment: @gugabrielle what processors/compiler are you using?  Do you have access to Intel vectoring?  You can get huge performance increases by adding those extensions when using for loops.  This would be in addition to the above suggestions.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I run it without debugging

Comment: @user657267 I am sure i do not use at

Comment: @gugabrielle That doesn't answer my question.  Are you running a Release version?  If you get a subscript out-of-range error, then you are *not* running a release version of your program, as the only time you get those errors is when you are running a debug version of the program.  The error needs to be fixed, but you should be aware that if you time a debug version of your app, it is meaningless if you want to know how fast the program can actually run.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i use the local windows debugger

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie if running a release version, how to set it?

Comment: If this is Visual Studio, you have "Debug" and "Release" configurations.  You are currently using the "Debug" configuration.  Change it to "Release" and rebuild your program (but you still need to fix your error).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am trying the release version now

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this for loop it is much much faster under the release configuration that is 4''. but for the second question, the running time is still not that efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are repeatedly multiplying by the values in expn (i.e. calculating an exponent) you can do this more efficiently using the pow function and get rid of the zz loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 141; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 1202; j++) 
    {
        for (k = 0; k < 141; k++)
        {   
            if (Ktemp[i][j][k].real() <= 0)
            {
                excit_pfft[i][j][k] = 0;  
            }
            else
            {
                excit_pfft[i][j][k] = excit_pfft[i][j][k] * pow(expn[i][j][k], 20);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your code also seems to have a memory leak because you assign P1 to excit_pfft, but never free the previous contents of excit_pfft. You don't need to have the P1 temporary array in any case once you get rid of the outer loop.

I'm not sure of the internals of the complex pow() function, but you can calculate the (scalar) exponent of a complex number geometrically by converting it to polar co-ordinates (angle + distance scalar), then multiplying the angle by the power and raising the distance to the power, then converting back. So it's a lot faster than repeated multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

First (will probably give you a big performance boost), get rid of the pointer arrays if you know beforehand the size of your arrays and simply allocate them in the stack:

```
complex<double> P1[141][1202][141];
```

Instead of :

```
complex<double> ***P1;
P1 = new complex<double>**[141];
for (i = 0; i < num_y; i++)
{
    P1[i] = new complex<double> *[1202];
    for (j = 0; j < tsize; j++)
    {
        P1[i][j] = new complex<double>[141];
    }
}
```

And since I don't know exactly what this does, I'm assuming this:

```
    for (int zz = 1; zz < 20; zz++)//in z direction
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 141; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 1202; j++) 
            {
                for (k = 0; k < 141; k++)
                {   
                    if (Ktemp[i][j][k].real() <= 0)
                    {
                        P1[i][j][k] = 0;  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        P1[i][j][k] = excit_pfft[i][j][k] * expn[i][j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        excit_pfft = P1;    
    }
```

Could become this:

```
    for (int zz = 1; zz < 20; zz++)//in z direction
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 141; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 1202; j++) 
            {
                for (k = 0; k < 141; k++)
                {   
                    if (Ktemp[i][j][k].real() <= 0)
                    {
                        P1[i][j][k] = 0;  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        P1[i][j][k] = P1[i][j][k] * expn[i][j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

If this cannot be done than I'll need a more broad chunk of this code to analyze excit_pfft, etc.

A huge performance boost you could have is to use Worker Threads and run this last code multithreaded.

The same goes for our second question, Worker Threads should do it.

EDIT:
On second though, the stack won't be able to handle that much variables.
I'd recommend using `vector<vector<vector<complex<double> > > >` instead.

Comment: Uh...allocating ~400MB on the stack? You're going to have a bad time.

Comment: `complex<double> P1[141][1202][141];`  I doubt your stack has this much space.

Comment: You're right, I didn't considered the size... I'll edit the answer to use vector instead.

Comment: @AymarFisherman in the code below, there will be error: subscript out of range ...                                                                                                                  int num_y = 141;
 int t_cyc = 1202;
 int num_x = 141;
 vector<vector<vector<complex<double>>>> P1;
 P1.reserve(num_y);
 for (i = 0; i < num_y; i++)
 {
  P1[i].reserve(t_cyc);
  for (j = 0; j < t_cyc; j++)
  {
   P1[i][j].reserve(num_x);
   for (k = 0; k < num_x;k++)
   {
    P1[i][j].push_back(3);
   }
  }
 }